# Why do I get different themes logged in as an authenticated user versus anonymous?

Tags: theme, authentication

Any ideas why when I change the theme of a site and log in as an authenticated user that it is not the same when I go back to the site as an anonymous user?

Basically one site is showing up with 2 different themes - one theme when I log on as an authenticated user and another when logged in as an anonymous user.

Can you help with this?

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint Foundation does not support Themes for anonymous users. So your anonymous users will always see the default theme.

Answer (score 1):

See here - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617146.aspx

"If you apply a theme to a SharePoint Foundation 2010 site, anonymous users who browse the site will see only the default theme. To make the selected theme appear for all users, you must add a link in the master page to the generated CSS file."

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a custom master page? I have seen this happen when a master page is not published and approved - authenticated users would get the updated and the anonymous users got the previous version.

Comment: No i'm not using a custom page.I'm using Sharepoint Foundation 2010.
When you say Publish how can i publish master pages from Sharepoint Foundation 2010?Although i have noticed the publish link coming up when i view the page as an anonymous user when when i login in it just dissapears.Any ideas?